# CORS request did not succeed while trying Github pages hosted static website with Facebook graph API

Tags: firefox, facebook-graph-api, github-pages, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to host a static website via Github pages. I am using HTML, CSS and JS to connect to Graph API from Facebook and then display the name of connected user via a button press.
I tested the functionality using Firefox browser on two different machines - a desktop PC and a laptop.
While the hosted website works in Firefox browser on one machine (laptop), it fails to display the connected user while using Firefox browser on the desktop machine.

I tried to debug the problem by inspecting the console in browser. Then I see the following error message -

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://graph.facebook.com
```

I have seen other COR related questions but they did not use Facebook Graph API.
Any hints on where I could be going wrong considering the hosted website works perfectly on a different machine using Firefox browser ?